# How to increase the quality of product photos JPG (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, product-images

The JPG compression on Magento 2 is very strong, so that the quality of product images get really bad in Catalog and Product view. How can I change the Image compression for JPG's in Magento 2?

Answer (score 16):

This solution works for me  :

File : {Vendor}/{Module}/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image" type="{Vendor}\{Module}\Model\Product\Image" />
</config>
```

File : {Vendor}/{Module}/Model/Product
You can set the quality to whatever you want. Then flush image cache.

```
namespace {Vendor}\{Module}\Model\Product;

class Image extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image {

    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_quality = 100;

        parent::_construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the path to put this file in your custom theme? i cant figure out M2s filing structure. M1 was sooooo much easier

Comment: In app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}

Comment: but wont that get overridden during upgrade? i thought you would have to put it in your theme. no?

Comment: No, the {Vendor} folder must be replaced by you namespace (could be styzzz by example). It won't be overridden. Ex.: /app/code/styzzz/ImageCompression/...

Comment: If you have PNG image for product, the compression level is hardcoded in the GD2 adapter : `vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php:167` to 9 (max)

Comment: Although this solution looks promising, the product images in the catalog view still look grainy. I even tried @LW71 's approach (Magento 2.3.0).

Comment: hi,are you fixed? @EightBitBoy

Comment: This is correct. I made a module to make it easier to edit this value in the admin. See https://github.com/superdav42/magento-image-quality. Just installing it will increase the quality to 85 but you can change it to whatever you want in the admin. Using 100 is actually not a good idea as it will greatly increase your file size and have no noticeable increase in quality from something more reasonable like 92.

Answer (score 14):

As for Magento 2.3.2 it's possible to set image quality without changing the code:

*Stores > Configuration > Advanced > System > Images Upload Configuration > Quality > 100*

XML config path is:

```
system/upload_configuration/jpeg_quality
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/165511)

Comment: "How can I change the Image compression for JPG's in Magento 2"... Wasn't this the question?

Comment: better than the other answers as no code change required

Comment: This is the definitive answer, the code in the other examples is marked with deprecated in current M2.

Answer (score 3):

inside - vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Image.php

You will find the generic:

```
public function setQuality($quality)
{
    $this->_getModel()->setQuality($quality);
    return $this;  
}
```

If you grep for its usage you will find a method of the same name in:

magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Image.php

and inside that file:

```
/**
 * Default quality value (for JPEG images only).
 *
 * @var int
 */         
protected $_quality = 80;
```

It is this value - that needs setting to 95.

This will reduce the compression and artefacts in the site.

Your guys will i assume have to make this modifications with a suitably deployed code override - i.e. not by modification of this core file. Im not a magento developer otherwise i'd have a crack....

Comment: Actually, changing any values in the Core (vendor) will be overwritten with the next update, so changing core files is in general a bad idea

Answer (score 3):

The answers here are pretty wrong IMO. It's not the quality you should be changing **first hand**, it's the size of the images. Why?

Well the thing is when compressing an image to get the smallest possible file size then the compression rate is the most beneficial in achieving that goal. The second one is the dimensions of the image. Also you should always compress the original source image before downsizing it (I haven't checked how magento handles this) to get the file size down as much as possible whilst preserving details.

On retina screens you need 2x the displayed size. So in order to get a sharp image displayed at 250x250 pixels, then the image needs to be 500x500 pixels.

So I'd start with changing in the themes `view.xml` to double the displayed size. If the image still doesn't look good then I'd consider upping the quality setting. If you have time you could **implement responsive** images as well (so doubled sizes are **only loaded on retina screen devices**).

You can also get the size down by removing all meta data from the image, not sure if magento does that by default or not. It's usually a part of good image compressing services.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this mate! I knew there must be a logical reason for magento's image tomfoolery! I'm still a bit confused about implementation though. So, say my products are displaying on the product page as a 700px square, then I would need to create an image that is 1400px square, then change the corresponding setting in the view.xml file to 1400px as well?

I have been playing with this, as well as the override mentioned in other answers, but the quality is always lower on the product page than it is when I click on the image to enter the 'zoomed' view.

Comment: @JoshuaFlood I think the zoomed image has it's own entry in view.xml with a bigger size, can't remember exactly what key it has or what size it is though

Comment: No worries I sorted it. Thanks for the tip! Not sure exactly what did it but I had forgotten to replace the 'small' images with the double-sized ones, so the problem could be there.

Comment: This is not a good answer. What you should do is use responsive images and the srcset attribute - not just provide a larger image in general that will be downscaled whenever necessary.

Comment: @fritzmg "first hand" "If you have time you could implement responsive images as well".. which part do you find difficult to understand?

Comment: I am sorry, missed that.