# How to increase the quality of product photos JPG (Magento 2.1)

Tags: magento2, product-images

The JPG compression on Magento 2.1 is very strong, so that the quality of product images get really bad in Catalog and Product view. How can I change the Image compression for JPG's in Magento 2.1 ?

Comment: you can create a small module, this works for me : http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/137878/40340

Answer (score 0):

I found this [How to increase the quality of product photos JPG (Magento 2)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113165/how-to-increase-the-quality-of-product-photos-jpg-magento-2?rq=1),

inside - `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Image.php`

You will find the generic:

```
public function setQuality($quality)
{
    $this->_getModel()->setQuality($quality);
    return $this;  
}
```

If you grep for its usage you will find a method of the same name in:

```
magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Image.php
```

and inside that file:

```
/**
 * Default quality value (for JPEG images only).
 *
 * @var int
 */         
protected $_quality = 80;
It is this value - that needs setting to 95.
```

it works, but it's modification of the core file.

What we need is the code bellow from M1 for M2.

> echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(),
>   'image', $_image->getFile())->resize(42, 50)->setQuality(95);

problem is where to add this in

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/
```

Comment: I made a module to make it easier to edit this value in the admin. See github.com/superdav42/magento-image-quality. Just installing it will increase the quality to 85 but you can change it to whatever you want in the admin.