# Magento 2 low image quality on products

Tags: magento2, php-7, gd2, image-quality

We are currently using Magento 2 and all the images uploaded to the website are resized or modified by the system. The result is a poor image quality on all the products.

I'm not finding any configuration on the backend to change this settings and I understand that's managed directly from que PHP Image library.

That's our current env:

- **Container 1:** MariaDB
- **Container 2:** Redis (for Magento's cache)
- **Container 3:** Apache 2.4 + PHP 7 (modphp and PHP GD2)
- **Container 4:** Cron
- **Container 5:** Varnish 4
- **Container 6:** Redis (for autodiscovery cluster nodes)
- **Container 7:** Nginx SSL terminator

I checked on the **Settings -> Developer** you can switch to Image Magick. It's this the solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the quality of image is set in `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image` at line no 43 `protected $_quality = 80;` you can override this in you module

> See How to override [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113165/how-to-increase-the-quality-of-product-photos-jpg-magento-2)

Comment: This is correct. I made a module to make it easier to edit this value in the admin. See https://github.com/superdav42/magento-image-quality. Just installing it will increase the quality to 85 but you can change it to whatever you want in the admin.