# What is GD2 and ImageMagick in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2.2, image-upload, gd2

Can any one explain what is the use of GD2 and ImageMagick while uploading images in backend in magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick delivers better quality images on front end. It may however slow the loading of your pages. I do not believe that it has any relation/affect on uploading images via the Admin.

Other posts that have helped me:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392936/how-to-upload-a-image-on-imagemagick

[Magento 2: Image Processing Settings - GD2 V/s ImageMagick](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174108/magento-2-image-processing-settings-gd2-v-s-imagemagick)

[Magento 2 low image quality on products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163022/magento-2-low-image-quality-on-products)

Comment: According to https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22080 ImageMagick would also fix some issues you might find (like I did) with GD