# Magento 2: Override product image JPG quality

Tags: product, model, magento2.2, class, image-quality

Magento 2.2.1 with custom theme which inherits from `Magento/blank`.

Attempting to fix the JPG compression for product images.

I know, based on [this solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113165/how-to-increase-the-quality-of-product-photos-jpg-magento-2), that I must extend the Image class found here:

> Magento_Catalog/Model/Product/Image.php

I now understand the basic file structure properly, thanks to Quan Le's answer.

I have created the following structure:

```
+-- app
    +-- code
        +-- [Vendor]
            +-- module-image-fix
                +-- registration.php
                +-- etc
                    +-- di.xml
                    +-- module.xml
                +-- Model
                    +-- Product
                        +-- Image.php
```

I know that there is a problem here, but I can't work out how to properly label directories within the files themselves. The solution I am working from does not clearly label the files or file structure, so I'm not sure if I even need `registration.php` etc.

I have tried renaming `module-image-fix` to `ImageFix` with no luck.

#### registration.php

```
<?php
  \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
  \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
  '[Vendor]_ImageFix',
  __DIR__
);
```

#### di.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product" type="[Vendor]\ImgFix\Model\Product" />
  </config>
```

#### module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="[Vendor]_ImageFix" setup_version="1.0.1">
        </module>
    </config>
```

#### Image.php

```
<?php
    namespace [Vendor]\ImageFix\Model\Product;
    class Image extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image {
        protected function _construct() {
            $this->_quality = 100;
            return parent::_construct();
        }
    }
```

I have so far managed to successfully enable the module, but without any change to images.

I have also managed to enable the module, but received an error that `[Vendor]/ImageFix/Models/Product` does not exist.

Comment: I made a module to make it easier to edit this value in the admin. See github.com/superdav42/magento-image-quality. Just installing it will increase the quality to 85 but you can change it to whatever you want in the admin. Using 100 is actually not a good idea as it will greatly increase your file size and have no noticeable increase in quality from something more reasonable like 92. Also you may have to delete everything in `pub/media/catalog/product/cache/`.

Comment: @DavidStone thanks a lot! I'm currently working on other things but will implement this soon. The company that's going to use the template is one I work for, so I was compressing the images myself externally, to an appropriate size, then uploading them at 100% in magento. Is this still going to cause problems, or is it mainly in cases where a client has sent 100s of images and won't pay for the extra time it would take to manually fix them?

Comment: This will likely still cause issues. All the thumbnails and image preview will be generated by magento at a lower quality. Manually changing the quality before uploading will make no difference. You need to make the code changes or use my extension for it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep your custom module in `app/code` folder follow Magento 2 Module Structure like this

[image]

Comment: As of Magento 2.2, modules are no longer stored within `app/code/<Vendor_Name>/<Module_Name>`, as explained in my original question. They are stored inside `vendor/<Vendor_Name>/<Module_Name>`. The `app/code` directory no longer exists in 2.2. See documentation here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_intro.html

Comment: I'm just not sure how I should override the Magento_Catalog app in order to alter the jpg quality in the Product model.

Comment: I don't know if you've already read this line - "But if you are creating a new module for distribution, you can just create the app/code/<vendor>/<type>-<module-name> directory and the required directories within it."
There are many tutorials, you can check this one for overriding classes http://inchoo.net/magento-2/overriding-classes-magento-2/

Comment: And the files can still be read by magento, even though it does not own an `app/code` directory already created?  Maybe I am just misunderstanding some of the terminology.

Comment: I think my problem is actuall in understanding the linked solution. They explain the di.xml file, as well as how to write the file which extends `Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Image`, but they don't explain where to store that file exactly, or how it should be named. So when I enable the module I get an error which states `<Vendor>/<Module>/Model/Product` does not exist.

Comment: Where would I store a model in your screenshotted example?